# RefineSlide not showing up on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I'm testing a new jquery slider; [RefineSLide](https://github.com/webbart/refineslide), but it doesn't seem to be showing up in the webpage. I went through the refineslide .css and .js files couldn't find anything that could be causing a problem. Any ideas?

Html for entire test site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="testing" />

  <link href="refineslide.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>


<body>


<ul class="rs-slider">
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="2.jpg" alt=""/></li>
  <li><img src="3.jpg" alt=""/></li>
</ul>





<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("rs-slider").refineSlide();
    });
</script>



<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<srcipt src="jquery.refineslide.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo, you used in `srcipt` word instead of `script` in the following line:

```
<srcipt src="jquery.refineslide.js"></script>
```

Where as it should be:

```
<script src="jquery.refineslide.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you!   Though that didn't seem to fix the problem. There must be more...